# Add a comments meta box to the custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types

I have created a custom post type called groups and I would like to add the comments meta field to this edit groups page. Any ideas that would help me?
Thank you.

Comment: please check:https://www.sitepoint.com/adding-meta-boxes-post-types-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

I figured a simple solution for this

```
          'supports' => array(
          'title',
          'editor',
          'revisions',
          'comments',
          )
```